# Comparison of Boost StateCharts vs. Samek's "Quantum Statecharts"

Tags: c++, boost, comparison, state-machine

I've had heavy exposure to Miro Samek's "Quantum Hierarchical State Machine," but I'd like to know how it compares to Boost StateCharts - as told by someone who has worked with both.  Any takers?

Comment: Only thing I really know, having only used boost's, is that the code gets pretty ungainly and hard to manage really, really quickly.  The declarative syntax for states is not at all natural.  At least I didn't find it to be.

Comment: @Noah: interesting comment.  Samek's approach scales very nicely; huge statecharts are handled as easily as small.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know them both, although at different detail levels. But we can start with the differences I've came across, maybe there are more :-) .

### Scope

First, the Quantum Platform provides a complete execution framework for UML state machines, whereas boost::statechart only helps the state machine implementations. As such, boost::statechart provides the same mechanism as the event processor of the Quantum Platform (QEP).

### UML Conformance

Both approaches are designed to be UML conform. However, the Quantum Platform executes transition actions **before** exit actions of the respective state. This contradicts the UML, but in practice this is seldom a problem (if the developer is aware of it).

Boost::statechart is designed according to UML 1.4, but as far as I know the execution *semantics* did not change in UML 2.0 in an incompatible way (please correct me if I'm wrong), so this shouldn't be a problem either.

### Supported UML features

Both implementations do not support the full UML state machine feature set. For example, parallel states (aka AND states) are not supported directly in QP. They have to be implemented manually by the user. Boost::statechart does not support internal transitions, because they were introduced in UML 2.0.

I think the exact features that each technique supports are easy to figure out in the documentation, so I don't list them here.

As a fact, both support the most important statechart features.

### Other differences

Another difference is that QP is suitable for embedded applications, whereas boost::statechart maybe is, maybe not. The FAQ says "it depends" (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/statechart/doc/faq.html#EmbeddedApplications), but to me this is already a big warning sign.

Also, you have to take special measurements to get boost::statechart real-time capable (see FAQ).

So much to the differences that I know, tell me if you find more, I'd be interested!

Comment: Does boost::statechart support hierarchical states, or only flat state charts?

Comment: Yes it does. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/statechart/doc/index.html#Overview for a feature list. By the way, you may want to take a look at boost::MSM (meta state machine), which is new in Boost 1.44. It seems to have a better SM definition syntax, but I don't really know it.

Answer (score 4):

I have also worked with both, let me elaborate on theDmi's great answer:

Trace capability: 
QP also implements a powerful trace capability called QSpy which enables very fine granularity traces with filter capabilities. With boost you have to roll your own and you never get beyond a certain granularity.

Modern C++ Style and Compile time error checking:
While Boost MSM and Statecharts give horrid and extremely long error messages if you mess up (as does all code written by template geniuses I envy), this is far better than runtime error detection. QP uses Q_ASSERT() and similar macros to do some error checking but in general you have to watch yourself more with QP and code is less durable. 
I also find the extensive use of the preprocessor in QP takes a bit of getting used to. It may be warranted to use the preprocessor rather than templates, virtual functions etc. because of QPs use in embedded systems where the C++ compilers are often worse and the hardware is less virtual function friendly but sometimes I wish Mr. Samek would make a C, a C++ and a Modern C++ version ;) Rumor has it I'm not the only one who hates the preprocessor.

Scalability:
Boost MSM is not good for anything above 20 states, Statecharts has pretty much no limit on states but the amount of transitions a state can have is limited by the mpl::vector/list constraints. QP is scalable to an insane degree, virtually unlimited states and transitions are possible. It should also be noted that QP state machines can be spread over many many files with few dependencies.

Model driven development:
because of its extreme scalability and flexibility QP is much better suited for Model Driven Development, see this article for a lengthy comparison: http://security.hsr.ch/mse/projects/2011_Code_Generator_for_UML_State_Machines.pdf

Embedded designs:
QP is the only solution for any kind of embedded design in my mind. Its documented down to the bare bones so its easily portable, ports exist for many many common processors and it brings a lot of stuff with it beyond the state machine functionality. I particularly like the raw thread safe queues and memory management. I have never seen an embedded kernel I liked until I tried the RTC Kernel in QP (although it should be noted I have not used it in production code yet).

Answer (score -2):

I am unfamiliar with Boost StateCharts, but something I feel Samek gets wrong is that he associates transition actions with state context.  Transition actions should occur between states.

To understand why I don't like this style requires an example:

What if a state has two different transitions out?  Then the events are different but the source state would be the same.

In Samek's formalism, transition actions are associated with a state context, so you have to have the same action on both transitions.  In this way, Samek does not allow you to express a pure Mealy model.

While I have not provided a comparison to Boost StateCharts, I have provided you with some details on how to critique StateCharts implementations: by analyzing coupling among the various components that make up the implementation.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. My implementation technique supports both actions on transitions (Mealy automata) and entry/exit actions associated with states (Moore automata). For example, the Dr. Dobbs article "UML at $10.99" (http://www.drdobbs.com/embedded-systems/188101799) shows a pedestrian crossing state machine that uses both actions on internal transitions and entry/exit actions.
--Miro Samek

Comment: @user429921: There certainly is no bug in Samek's approach.  It is true that Samek's transition actions "physically" execute while still in the departing state.  However, "logically," it is a non-sequitor to deduce non-compliance with Mealy (partly because Samek does not allow two events to be handled concurrently in one state machine, rather he follows a RTC model).

Comment: @Mystagogue: It is true that you need some logical rule for ensuring coherence.  I should NOT have used the word "bug" to describe Samek's system (apologies).  Rather, I should have said "To understand [WHY I DON'T LIKE THIS STYLE], requires an example".  The upshot of Samek decision for transition actions executing "physically" while still in the departing state is that they are conceptually coupled to the source state.  Do you think there is a better way to analyze library design?  Basics include feature parity, performance, documentation, defect track record.

Comment: Why executing transition actions in the source state context is bad? Why executing transition actions in the least-common-ancestor of source and target LCA(source, target) is a better alternative? Actually, I was trying to get this explained for years.

Comment: @user429921: I suggest it is only "conceptually coupled" if you don't make a distinction between logical and physical.  If you think and code as if they are not coupled, no latent behaviorial anomolies will emerge.  This is why, I propose, the physical representation is moot.